# Enumerate 10 letters combinations from {A B C D E F G} with at most 3 A's and at least 1 F

Tags: combinatorics

> How many ways to choose a 10 letter combination from {A B C D E F G} such that there is at most 3'A's and at least 1'F'.

Here are my thoughts:

- Let X be the property that it would have at most 3'A's
- Let Y be the property that it would have at least 1 'F'

$\mid X\mid = 6^{10} + 6^{9} + 6^{8} + 6^ {7} $ which correspond to the number of way with 0'A', 1'A's, 2'A's and 3'A's respectively

$\mid Y\mid = 7^{10} - 6^{10}$ because total possible ways is $\ 7^{10}$ and the number of ways without F would be $\ 6^{10}$

Then after which, how should I proceed from here?

Comment: Choose 9 letters apart from the compulsory $F$, and try computing directly.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint #1**: We only want to include such combinations with at least one F. How many of these are there?

**Hint #2**: *Of the included combinations*, we must exclude those that have $4$ or more As. How many of those are there?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have *specifically* been asked to use inclusion-exclusion, it is easier to directly compute choosing 9 letters apart from the compulsory $F$.

$(0 A's, 9$ others) + $(1 A, 8$ others) $+$ ......

Think of stars and bars for the "others"

> e,g, for $9$ "others", $\dbinom{9+6-1}{6-1} = \dbinom{14}{5}$